# How can I load a trained model in Azure ML Studio?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

I'm trying to load a trained model from the trained models tab in Azure ML studio into another experiment. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/load-trained-model#load-the-model-into-a-new-experiment) its possible to do as follows:

> Add the Load Trained Model module to your experiment. For Data source,
>   indicate the location of the trained model, using one of the following
>   options:
>       Select Web URL via HTTP and then type the URL.
>       The URL should point to the experiment and the file representing the trained model. In Azure Machine Learning, trained models are by
>   default saved in the iLearner format.

However, does anyone know what URL I would use for models saved in my workspace? Where is the file representing the model hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Pffff. never mind. I was trying to work with the 'load trained model' module under data input and output. Completely oblivious that there was a 'trained models' module as well.